# Laravel PSR-16 Cache. Adapting \Predis\Client to \Redis?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

I am trying to use the laravel redis cache inside a package that requires a PSR-16 cache. I have found the following way to get this working:

```
class_alias('\Predis\Client', '\Redis'); // rename \Predis\Client to \Redis

$client = Redis::connection('default');
$pool = new \Cache\Adapter\Redis\RedisCachePool($client->client());
$simpleCache = new \Cache\Bridge\SimpleCache\SimpleCacheBridge($pool);
$psr16_cache = new SimpleCacheTokenPersistence($simpleCache);
```

As you can see... the first line is very hacky! The class name to be accepted by the RedisCachePool, which will only accept a \Redis object.

No matter what I have tried, I cannot get Laravel to provide a Redis object even though the Predis\Client is identical.

Other than the hack my other option would be to fork the the php-cache/redis-adapter package but again its not ideal.

Can anyone suggest any workarounds to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `predis-adapter` instead of the `redis-adapter`

`composer require cache/predis-adapter`

Github: https://github.com/php-cache/predis-adapter